# I want to hide share and go to you tube option in my iframe video box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have iframe video box in this I Want to disable share option and go to you tube in my iframe video box.
enter image description here

[image]

My code:

```
 <div class="container">     
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2 align="center"></h2>
       <?php foreach ($fetchvideos as $fetchvideo) : ?>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 " style="position: relative;" >
       <iframe oncontextmenu="return false" class="yt_players"  id="<?php echo $fetchvideo->id?>" width="972" height="284" src="<?php echo $fetchvideo->Links?>?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">
       </style> allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
players = new Array();
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var temp = $("iframe.yt_players");
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var t = new YT.Player($(temp[i]).attr('id'), {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        players.push(t);
    }
}
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    var temp = event.target.getVideoUrl();
    var tempPlayers = $("iframe.yt_players");
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (players[i].getVideoUrl() != temp) players[i].stopVideo();
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I do not know to do it.

[image]

Comment: The problem is, this is an embed CROSS site. It operates through inserting a document from another site, which you cannot modify. This is simply not possible.

Comment: @FrankerZ what is the alternative solution for this

Comment: Why would youtube allow you to use their platform on your site without having any links back to their site? If you have a payed account, you get more options but even then, I doubt you can remove all links back to youtube.

Comment: Alternative? Don't use youtube? Use your own embeds, with your own platform?